# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 1551: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I m trying check Wifi password program on Python so I  encounter some problem about unicodeDecodeError I couldn't understand

Here  is my uptading terminal:

```
C:\Users\bartu\Desktop\Python\pythonSmallProject>python check_wifi_password.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_wifi_password.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profiles']).decode(get_encoding).split('\n') # now we will store the profiles data in the "data" variable by
TypeError: decode() argument 'encoding' must be str,  not function
```

here is my uptading code:

```
import subprocess   # first we will import the subprocess module
import os
from chardet import detect

def get_encoding(file):
    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return detect(data)['encoding']

data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profiles']).decode(get_encoding).split('\n') # now we will store the profiles data in the "data" variable by
                                                                                               # running the 1st cmd command using subprocess.check_output
profiles =  [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in data  if "All User Profile" in i]  # now we will store the profile by converting them to list

# using  for loop in python we re checking and printing the Wifi
# passwords  if they  are avaiable using the 2nd cmd command
for i in profiles:
    # running the 2nd cmd command to check  passwords
    results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profile',i,'key = clear']).decode(get_encoding).split('\n')
    # storing passwords after converting them to list
    results = [j.split(":")[1][1:-1]  for j in results if " Key Content" in j]
    # printing the profiles(wifi name) with their passwords using
    # try and except
try:
    print("{:<30} | {:<}".format(i,results[0]))
except IndexError:
    print("{:<30} | {:<}".format(i, ""))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print("{:<30} | {:<}".format(i, "ENCODING ERROR"))
print("")
```

Comment: Did you try `print(results)` to see if it really is what you expect it to be?

Comment: The capital I you use to spell `ENCODING` does not look like standard ascii. Is it possible that your machine uses an encoding different from utf-8?

Comment: my fault ı change it to ENCODING

Comment: That was not a problem, print whatever you want :) It just made me aware that you most probably have your system configured using a non-ascii encoding and thus your output might not be encoded in `utf-8`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `latin` encoding?

```
data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profiles']).decode('latin1').split('\n')
```

If it doesn't work, try getting the encoding from the file-

```
import os    
from chardet import detect

def get_encoding(data):
    return detect(data)['encoding']

data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh','wlan','show','profiles'])
data_encoding = get_encoding(data)
decoded_data = data.decode(data_encoding).split('\n')
```

Comment: Does `bytes.decode` work with a function as argument? The idea is great,  but I'd use `get_encoding` on the result of `check_output` and then decode that result with the encoding found by `get_encoding`.

Comment: decode() argument 'encoding'  must be str, not function